# Array condition in php if the variable exist in an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, object

I am creating a function to return a date, where I have a data array with objects inside of it and i want to insert in separate array the dates that are the same from my data array with status 1 and 2 .

Here is my array object data:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [time] => 2019-09-09 09:00:00 [status] => 1 )
        [1] => stdClass Object ( [time] => 2019-09-09 17:00:00 [status] => 2 ) 
        [2] => stdClass Object ( [time] => 2019-09-10 09:00:00 [status] => 1 )
        [3] => stdClass Object ( [time] => 2019-09-10 17:00:00 [status] => 2 )
        [4] => stdClass Object ( [time] => 2019-09-11 09:00:00 [status] => 1 )
        [5] => stdClass Object ( [time] => 2019-09-11 17:00:00 [status] => 2 )
        [6] => stdClass Object ( [time] => 2019-09-12 09:00:00 [status] => 1 )
        [7] => stdClass Object ( [time] => 2019-09-13 09:00:00 [status] => 1 )
)
```

i want to return something like this array :

```
Array [0] 2019-09-09
      [1] 2019-09-10
      [2] 2019-09-11
```

I am getting this result from a database.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: If this is the output of a database query, it would be just as easy to do it in the query.

Comment: @EternalHour i don't know what to do first, i maybe thinking that i can use the function called in_array() ? but i figured out that i cannot because of the status

Comment: @Nick i am thinking of a query but i think i cannot filter the date if i have multiple exact date and have the same status

Comment: So you want to separate the objects with different status into different array?

Comment: @EternalHour yes and also i forgot something, also what if i have two same date with status 1 and i want to make the second date to not included as part of data

Comment: If you're thinking of a query, does that mean you get these results from a database?

Comment: @Qirel yes, these data's are came from database but i think processing in php is better than making it as query ?

Comment: Probably much better to do it in a query.

Comment: @Qirel btw, i'm not very good in making queries as well. Also thinking if there is duplicate date and status, and i want  to disregard the second data.

Comment: I agree with Qirel. If you are needing to filter out data in php from your query better to not even select it.

Comment: @EternalHour ok.. thanks i'll go edit my question and put something column names

Comment: Can there potentially be more than statuses `1` and `2`, or will it always be those two?

Comment: @Qirel I think the title needs to edited. Is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always expect the statuses to be either `1` or `2`, you can run a query where you select the `DISTINCT` values, where you use `DATE()` on the column. Then check if the date has both status 1 and 2.

Note that this solution doesn't scale that well if you can potentially have a lot of statuses - then you should consider a different approach.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(t.time) AS time
FROM myTable t
JOIN myTable t2 
  ON DATE(t.time) = DATE (t2.time)
WHERE t.status = 1
  AND t2.status = 2
ORDER BY t.time
```

- Live fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d57f12/2

The table

```sql
CREATE TABLE myTable (
  time DATETIME,
  status SMALLINT
);

INSERT INTO myTable VALUES
('2019-09-09 09:00:00', 1),
('2019-09-09 17:00:00', 2),
('2019-09-10 09:00:00', 1),
('2019-09-10 17:00:00', 2),
('2019-09-11 09:00:00', 1),
('2019-09-11 17:00:00', 2),
('2019-09-12 09:00:00', 1),
('2019-09-13 09:00:00', 1);
```

Produces the result

```
2019-09-09
2019-09-10
2019-09-11
```

Comment: whoa!. great answer. btw, what if i have something situation like this, ex. i have multiple status 1 with same date and i want to disregard the second data.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize `array_map()` function, Here is an example with your code

```
$dateArray = ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [time] => 2019-09-09 09:00:00 [status] => 1 )
        [1] => stdClass Object ( [time] => 2019-09-09 17:00:00 [status] => 2 ) 
        [2] => stdClass Object ( [time] => 2019-09-10 09:00:00 [status] => 1 )
        [3] => stdClass Object ( [time] => 2019-09-10 17:00:00 [status] => 2 )
        [4] => stdClass Object ( [time] => 2019-09-11 09:00:00 [status] => 1 )
        [5] => stdClass Object ( [time] => 2019-09-11 17:00:00 [status] => 2 )
        [6] => stdClass Object ( [time] => 2019-09-12 09:00:00 [status] => 1 )
        [7] => stdClass Object ( [time] => 2019-09-13 09:00:00 [status] => 1 )

)

$data = array_map('foo',$dateArray);
var_dump($data);
function foo($data){
    if($data->status == 1){
        return $data->time;
    }
}

var_dump(array_filter($data,'strlen'));
```

And the Output is

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "2019-09-13 07:16:33"
  [2]=>
  string(19) "2019-09-13 07:16:33"
  [5]=>
  string(19) "2019-09-13 07:16:33"
}
```

Comment: No, that's not what the output is... https://3v4l.org/Zklmc You get only where the status is 1. The OP asked where the dataset has a matching date with status 1 AND status 2.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the DB query solution which I prefer, this is a PHP solution

```
$dateArray = [
    ["time" => "2019-09-09 09:00:00", "status" => 1 ],
    ["time" => "2019-09-09 17:00:00", "status" => 2 ], 
    ["time" => "2019-09-10 09:00:00", "status" => 1 ],
    ["time" => "2019-09-10 17:00:00", "status" => 2 ],
    ["time" => "2019-09-11 09:00:00", "status" => 1 ],
    ["time" => "2019-09-11 17:00:00", "status" => 2 ],
    ["time" => "2019-09-12 09:00:00", "status" => 1 ],
    ["time" => "2019-09-13 09:00:00", "status" => 1 ]
];

$finalArray = [];

foreach($dateArray as $obj){
    //$obj is actually an array
    $date = new \DateTime($obj["time"]);
    $date = $date->format("Y-m-d");
    if (isset($finalArray[$date])){
        if ($obj["status"] == 1 && $finalArray[$date] === 2)  $finalArray[$date] = $obj;
        if ($obj["status"] == 2 && $finalArray[$date] === 1)  $finalArray[$date] = $obj;
    } else {
        $finalArray[$date] = ($obj["status"] == 1 ? 1 : 2);
    }

}


foreach($finalArray as $key => $obj){
    if (!is_array($obj)){
        unset($finalArray[$key]);
        continue;
    }
    echo $key . "\n";
}

//var_dump($finalArray);
```

This outputus

```
2019-09-09
2019-09-10
2019-09-11
```

Live demo https://3v4l.org/UuUVB

*Note: this solution is tuned for your case in the question, for example it supposes the status will be only 1, or 2*